# R conditional number change

Tags: r

I have two vectors:

`val` - containing eigenvalues

`vec` - containing eigenvectors

Using them I compute a square matrix (see code below):

```
val=c(8.4632323330381958, 0.83430218022179237, 0.22373186168113263)

vec=c(-0.40468599875813305, -2.2807177284758566, -0.57101165517074848, 
      -0.57101165517074848, -12.892899321073903, -29.43965303897123, 
      0.62945422198403489, 0.37595876464123751, 0.86002662343913638)

newMat<-matrix(vec, ncol=3)%*%diag(val)%*%t(matrix(vec, ncol=3))
```

**Now pay attention to the fact that the conditional number is** 8.46/0.22=37.8

Then I use R command `kappa(newMat)` in order to calculate the **conditional number and result is** 14984,  which is much greater than in reality!

Also, when I use `eigen(newMat)` in order to get eigenvectors and eigenvalues, I recieve absolutely different (from above mentioned) eigenvalues and eigenvectors and this difference could not be explained by standardization etc.

Please help me understand what is the reason of such results.

So the full code that will introduce the problem is:

```
val=c(8.4632323330381958, 0.83430218022179237, 0.22373186168113263)

vec=c(-0.40468599875813305, -2.2807177284758566, -0.57101165517074848, 
      -0.57101165517074848, -12.892899321073903, -29.43965303897123, 
      0.62945422198403489, 0.37595876464123751, 0.86002662343913638)

newMat<-matrix(vec, ncol=3)%*%diag(val)%*%t(matrix(vec, ncol=3))

max(val)/min(val)

kappa(newMat)

eigen(newMat)
```

Comment: Your eigenvectors don't seem to be orthogonal.  It might be helpful if you could post the matrix used to generate these eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: I don't have an initial matrix as I use iteretion maximization algorithm where eigenvectors and eigenvalues are parameters and I have restriction for eigenvalues to be greater then some particular values. Matrix that I get before my algorithm fails (due to negative definite matrix): matrix(c(1.7467031793885455, 14.006422915167448, 31.985771741674913, 14.0064229151674482, 182.738019307759714, 417.282696074095213, 31.9857717416749132, 417.282696074095270, 952.866022478541367), ncol=3)

Comment: It seems I have understand the problem. My algorithm do not control over orthogonality so QXQ^T is symmetric matrix but its eigenvectors and eigenvalues are different from those that are in QXQ^T. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to WaltS I understood that the problem was in nonorthogonal eigenvectoros.